# Вывод строки из переменной в столб

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Есть переменная `mylist` она содержит список. При выводе на экран с помощью

```
self.label2.setText("text{}".format(mystring))
```

Строка выходит видом `['text','text2']`
И выходит за экран. Как убрать [ ] и сделать чтобы каждый новый элемент в списке выводился в столбик.

Пример

```
'text',
'text2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for string in mystring:
    self.label2.setText("text{}".format(string))
```